# How to control text alignment and spacing in itemize?

Tags: formatting

I'd like to use long items in my `itemize` list. To control the alignment of items I use certain options (see example). However, this messed up the alignment of the text. How can I remove the indent in the first line?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, widest=99,leftmargin=*, labelsep=4.5em}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[Long item] This text is too long for a single line. But, as you can see, the alignment of the first line is different from the alignment of all other lines. How to fix that?
    \item[Longer item] Some text.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is not an itemsize when you manually type in `\item[...]` aren't the `description` env more what you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe, but the problem stays the same, even in the description env.

Comment: Have you looked in the `enumitem` manual. The style `nextline` might be of interest.

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to? it is not particularly obvious from your question. I'd switch to `description` and remove that ill-informed `labelsep`